# Compose: What is the proper way to add to a (Lazy)Column enough bottom padding to avoid the FAB to cover its content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button, lazycolumn

The issue is the very similar to the one [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290253/dynamically-setting-padding-widget-so-column-is-not-covered-by-fab) for Flutter, but happens in native Android using Jetpack Compose:

Is there a way to dynamically add bottom padding to a (Lazy)Column so its content is never obscured by the FAB?

The FAB is added to the Scaffold so I would expect some way to get this padding dynamically.

Comment: In this way you would have an empty space. Maybe the FAB is not the best solution in this case. You could use a Row at the bottom with a centered Button.

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, the use case is the same as Gmail and Google Contact app: it has a FAB on top of a list but, when you scroll to the bottom, there is enough padding for it to not block the content.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi What about adding extra padding to your last item ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try this though this may not be a good solution,

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    
    var fabHeight by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val heightInDp = with(LocalDensity.current) { fabHeight.toDp() }

    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    fabHeight = it.size.height
                },
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {},
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "icon")
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = heightInDp + 16.dp)
        ) {
            items(100) {
                Text(text = " Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world  Hello world")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Just simply add the modified paddings to contentPadding of `LazyColumn`

The hardcoded `16.dp` is added because internally the `Scaffold` implementations has a private property that offsets the `fab` from the bottom.

[image]

So having all of these will produce something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to not have to hardcode any padding value. It's a shame that the Scaffold doesn't expose it. Anyway, your solution can be improved replacing the item with the spacer with simply this set directly to the LazyColumn, after the modifier: `contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = heightInDp + 16.dp),`

Comment: Ohh yes,  thank you, that's a better way to do it, never thought of just adding the height of the `fab` that way, ill edit my answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the Below Code in LazyColumn.

```
 contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 16.dp) // put value as per you requirement
```